# Use index for GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM messages GROUP BY peer
```

(really it's more complicated with joins, but I omitted them here for simplicity)
The problem is that SQLite doesn't use any indexes and always performs a full scan of the table. Expectedly, it works fast on small data sets but it's noticeably slow with a big table containing thousands of rows. Here's the output of the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN command:
`0|0|0|SCAN TABLE messages USING INDEX messages_peer_mid (~1000000 rows)`
Despite it says "USING INDEX" it still performs a full scan. Is there any way to make SQLite use index for this query or it's better to give up with GROUP BY and look for some other approach?

Answer (score 0):

The plan takes into account the amount of data and performs a scan because it's algorithm probably concludes it's faster to do so.

Other comments, your query has no WHERE condition and you are returning ALL columns so why wouldn't you expect a table scan?

Comment: I think he said his query was just written as this for simplicity.

Comment: I can only comment on what I know.. for all I know his actual query has no where clause or one that still (obviously) requires a scan

Answer (score 0):

Indexes assist in *selecting* records from a table (using a `WHERE` clause or as a result of a `JOIN` operation).  `GROUP BY`  is performed on a set of records *after* they've been selected and retrieved from the table.  It cannot be assisted by indexes.

If you want to know more about what options are available for index use in your query, please post the entire query.

Also, you note that the SQL you gave is a symbolic representation of the code you're running, but if you're really using `*`, or any non-aggregated field names other than `peer` in your statement you may not be getting the results you want.

Finally, you ask "it's better to give up with GROUP BY and look for some other approach?"  `GROUP BY` is used for a specific function in SQL (producing new aggregated result sets from non-aggregated data).  If that's your goal, `GROUP BY` is likely to be the best solution (because it defers to the database engine, which is highly optimized and cognizant of database statistics the decision about how to retrieve and process the data).  If that's not your goal and you're trying to do something else using `GROUP BY` as an "approach" to that other functionality, let us know what it is you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I use this query to get a list of chats from a table containing messages. Actually I only need the ID of the last message from each chat (that's my mistake in the question); I can then select the details with a sub-query which will be fast because it uses index. By "other approach" I mean something like creating a separate table with these IDs and updating it using a trigger for example.

Comment: Are you after the latest message from *all* chats, or only for a subset of chats that interest you on any given screen of the application.  If you want help optimizing please edit your original question so that it has, at minimum, the full SQL (the table structures might also be relevant).